# Joining Two Tables With Union in Query

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to grab data from two tables and link them together, but I just can't see to make the query work.  Here's the query I've been running, and what I'm looking for the table to look like.

```
select playerid, sid, s.s_name, s.s_namelink, s.minsec FROM
((select max(points) as pts,
(
 select gd.date 
 from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
 where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
 order by t1.points desc limit 1
) as pts_date) UNION ALL (select points as pts, points_date as pts_date from game_high_reg)) as tot, from seasons s, game_stats_lakers t where t.playerid = 3 s.sid = t.sid group by playerid, sid
```

What my tables look like.

```
Table 1 - game_stats_lakers                               
playerid   sid   pts   pts_date
3          0304r 43    2003-11-23
3          0405r 40    2005-03-07
3          0910r 38    2009-12-23

Table 2 - game_high_reg
playerid   sid   points points_date
3          0506r 35     2006-03-23
3          0708r 34     2008-03-12
3          0809r 38     2009-02-23

What I'm Looking For                              
playerid   sid   pts   pts_date
3          0304r 43    2003-11-23
3          0405r 40    2005-03-07
3          0506r 35    2006-03-23
3          0708r 34    2008-03-12
3          0809r 38    2009-02-23
3          0910r 38    2009-12-23
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your desired output looks to be simply a UNION of the two tables but your query has a lot more going on in it including other tables.

Comment: Yeah the other table seasons s is just to pull cleaner names of the season.

Answer (score 1):

This will give your wanted result:

```
SELECT * FROM game_stats_lakers WHERE playerid = 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM game_high_reg WHERE playerid = 3
ORDER BY pts_date;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE game_stats_lakers  (
>   `playerid` INTEGER,
>   `sid` VARCHAR(8),
>   `pts` INT,
>   `pts_date` date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO game_stats_lakers 
>   (`playerid`, `sid`, `pts`, `pts_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '0304r' , '43', '2003-11-23'),
>   ('3', '0405r' , '40', '2005-03-07'),
>   ('3', '0910r' , '38', '2009-12-23');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE game_high_reg (
>   `playerid` INTEGER,
>   `sid` VARCHAR(8),
>   `points` INT,
>   `points_date` date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO game_high_reg
>   (`playerid`, `sid`, `points`, `points_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '0506r' , '35', '2006-03-23'),
>   ('3', '0708r' , '34', '2008-03-12'),
>   ('3', '0809r' , '38', '2009-02-23');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM game_stats_lakers WHERE playerid = 3
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM game_high_reg WHERE playerid = 3
> ORDER BY pts_date;
> ```
>
> ```
> playerid | sid   | pts | pts_date  
> -------: | :---- | --: | :---------
>        3 | 0304r |  43 | 2003-11-23
>        3 | 0405r |  40 | 2005-03-07
>        3 | 0506r |  35 | 2006-03-23
>        3 | 0708r |  34 | 2008-03-12
>        3 | 0809r |  38 | 2009-02-23
>        3 | 0910r |  38 | 2009-12-23
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0db136a4f3427aca4692e4505346c522)*

Comment: Problem is I don't want to create two new tables, the tables I have now are huge, I just want to pull the data from the both of them and merge them together.

Comment: This is what UNION does, it merges identical tables together and ignores identical rows.and it is quicker than JOINs

Comment: @nbk Your answer might be less confusing if you remove the `CREATE TABLE` part of it.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the logic of doing that, I just want to run a query, not alter any of my tables.  I guess I am confused.

Comment: @BANONE These represent *your* tables. But don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, name the columns you actually want returned

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it by using the union all command. It's not the prettiest thing in the world, but it does work for now.  This table has A LOT of columns.  Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction. Once I really thought about it, it was pretty easy actually.

```
select r.playerid, r.sid, se.s_name, se.s_namelink, se.minsec, se.lsbox, r.points as pts, r.points_date as pts_date, r.minutes as min, r.mp_date as min_date, r.seconds as sec, r.fgm, r.fgm_date, r.fga, r.fga_date, r.3ptm, r.3ptm_date, r.3pta, r.3pta_date, r.ftm, r.ftm_date, r.fta, r.fta_date, r.offr, r.offr_date, r.defr, r.defr_date, r.totr, r.totr_date, r.assists, r.assists_date as ast_date, r.steals, r.steals_date as stl_date, r.blocks, r.blocks_date as blk_date, r.turnovers, r.turnovers_date as to_date, r.personal_fouls, r.personal_fouls_date as pf_date from game_high_reg r, seasons se where r.playerid = 3 and r.sid LIKE '%r%' and r.sid = se.sid
union all
select
t.playerid,
t.sid,
s.s_name,
s.s_namelink,
s.minsec, 
s.lsbox,
max(points) pts,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.points desc limit 1
) pts_date,
max(min) min,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.min desc limit 1
) min_date,
(
    select t1.sec 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid
    order by t1.min desc limit 1
) sec,
max(fgm) fgm,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.fgm desc limit 1
) fgm_date,
max(fga) fga,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.fga desc limit 1
) fga_date,
max(3ptm) 3ptm,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.3ptm desc limit 1
) 3ptm_date,
max(3pta) 3pta,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.3pta desc limit 1
) 3pta_date,
max(ftm) ftm,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.ftm desc limit 1
) ftm_date,
max(fta) fta,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.fta desc limit 1
) fta_date,
max(offr) offr,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.offr desc limit 1
) offr_date,
max(defr) defr,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.defr desc limit 1
) defr_date,
max(totr) totr,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.totr desc limit 1
) totr_date, 
max(assists) assists,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.assists desc limit 1
) ast_date,
max(steals) steals,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.steals desc limit 1
) stl_date,
max(blocks) blocks,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.blocks desc limit 1
) blk_date,
max(turnovers) turnovers,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.turnovers desc limit 1
) to_date,
max(personal_fouls) personal_fouls,
(
    select gd.date 
    from game_stats_lakers t1, game_details gd 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid and t1.gid = gd.gid
    order by t1.personal_fouls desc limit 1
) pf_date
from game_stats_lakers t, seasons s where t.playerid = 3 and t.sid LIKE '%r%' and t.sid = s.sid
group by playerid, s_name;
```